# Smart Contract Tokens and exchanges?

Tags: contract-design, tokens, exchanges

Is there any special code you need so your token can be traded on exchanges example Binance?    Right now its a pretty basic contact like Fixed Supply token.

Or is it as long as the exchange(creates) has a etheruem wallet for your token, you can send your token to that exchange wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, your token needs to comply with a standard they support such as (but not limited to) ERC20. Doing so doesn't mean an automatic listing. You usually have to obtain their agreement.

Hope it helps.